# Solution for Bin-packing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a container with length of 2900cm, and i have 3 blocks with size of 1300cm, 1100cm, 800cm and a gap which have to appear between every 2 blocks so the size of the gap is 100cm, let me write like so:

```
container = 2900cm

block1 = 1300cm
block2 = 1100cm
block3 = 800cm 

gap = 100cm
```

Visual Example:  [Image-01](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoMn9VKDw-tcUQxaElPTGJuX28/view?usp=sharing)

solution that i want to get is:

```
[block2]-[gap]-[block3]-[gap]-[block3]
```

or

```
[1100]-[100]-[800]-[100]-[800]
```

Visual Example: [Image-02](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoMn9VKDw-tVlU2RUJWUEVrVkE/view?usp=sharing)

Alright, I heard about **bin-packing** and i like the concept(seems logical). but here are the questions:
1- How actually bin-packing work mathematically?
2- Is it related to **Factorization**(pre-algebra)?
3- Is Bin-packing the solution for this issue?

*I've read the Factorization concept and it's simple in examples they've provide, but couldn't find anything similar to what i have, i believe there should be a smart way of doing this.*

**My knowledge:** *I'm familiar with **pre-algebra**, **algebra 1** and **linear-algebra**, and **learn new things**.*

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, Each block can repeat it self.
**Edit:** I've added visual examples.

Comment: It's not clear what's the question. It's not clear if you want to put three blocks (with repetitions?) or an arbitrary number. The "solution I want to get" seems valid but arbitrary. Is is just an example? Do you want to enumerate all the possible arrangements, or what?

Comment: @leonbloy my question is how can i put those blocks and gaps in that length, like how bin-packing does that. and yes, each blocks and gaps can be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to bin packing, but in bin packing you have a fixed number of things to put in bins and you want to find the minimum number of bins.  It is also similar to the knapsack problem, where you want to find the most thinks that fit in a knapsack.

You need to specify your problem more closely.  For your specific instance, you can eliminate worrying about the gaps by adding 100 cm to each block and adding 100 cm to the length of the container to account for the gap that isn't there after the last block.  Then you are asking for the number of (ordered?) ways to (completely?) fill the container.  Factorization is not involved as we are just adding.  You can run afoul of common multiples trying to fill the container.  In your example the blocks are multiples of 100 cm, so no container that isn't such a multiple can be filled completely.

Comment: Thanks for point out the Knapsack problem, i just had quick look into it, it's pretty simple and straight forward, yeah, that's more like what i want, about benefit of each block, well, let's say the bigger size of block has highest benefit, so `Block1 , Block2, Block3` which are `1300cm,1100cm,800cm` has benefit of `3,2,1` but how can i fit the gap?
gap only will appear between blocks, so there should be 2 blocks, then there will be a gap between them, so adding it to block will cause extra 100cm extra, which i think it can actually effect the whole calculation, right?

Comment: The lack of a gap after the last block is why I suggested adding 100 cm to the container, then requiring a gap after the last block as well.  You then have the same number of gaps as blocks, so you can just add the 100 cm to each block.  You get the same set of solutions but don't have to worry about the gaps.

Comment: oh, That's right, very smart, thanks a lot. :D